# Install OS on a partitioned disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a disk partitioned in two drives: C--System, and D: Stuff. My operating system began to have problems, I removed the hard drive and deleted the partition C. When I installed the operating system again, everything worked without problems, but when I rebooted the PC, a message appears saying that no operating system is detected. Can I reinstall again, or do I need to make a backup of the data, format the hard drive and reinstall?

Comment: I wouldn't reinstall.  There is nothing wrong with what you are attempting to do.  It is either a funky master boot record and or no (or wrong) active partition selected.  It might be as simple as that.  Google "fix windows boot loader".  Also.. you will find some mighty fine free tools by Googling "hirens boot cd".  You can make a USB stick out of it if you don't have an optical drive.  Good luck.

Comment: ..."(or wrong) active partition selected. It might be as simple as that".                   Five years studying Computer Science for this. Thanks bro. It works